# Drools Deployment failed if more than 10 rules in DRL files

Tags: java, deployment, drools, rules

Anyone faces issue as subject refers?

I am trying to deploy a jar file to kie server using the restful api below. There is no error, it's just fail to deploy from the response of the api below. If reduce the # of rules below 10, then it works.

```
http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/containers/
```

XML value for the post command of the restful api above

```
<kie-container container-id = "efamily">
<release-id>
           <artifact-id>e-drools</artifact-id>
           <group-id>my.m.report</group-id>
           <version>1.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</release-id>

</kie-container>
```

below is my kmodule.xml config

```
  <kmodule xmlns="http://www.drools.org/xsd/kmodule" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
              <kbase name="KieBase" default="true" eventProcessingMode="stream" equalsBehavior="identity">
                <ksession name="KieSession" type="stateless" default="true" clockType="realtime"/>

          </kbase>
</kmodule>
```

Comment: what exception you can see if there are more than 10 rules ?